# Chamar classes a partir de strings em módulos ES6 (commonjs) compilados pelo Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, módulo-ecmascript

Em um projeto web com `TypeScript`, utilizando módulos `commonjs`, compilados através do Webpack (versão 5), necessito chamar classes e métodos dinamicamente a partir de variáveis do tipo `string` contendo os seus nomes.

Posso separar esses arquivos que serão utilizados "globalmente" através de pastas ou com uma extensão diferenciada. Em último caso, posso até criar um arquivo de índice para incluir manualmente todos os arquivos que necessitem ser acessados dessa forma.

O problema é que:

- Quando faço o INCLUDE, o Webpack torna as classes inacessíveis.
- Quando não faço o INCLUDE, o Webpack não insere as classes no `bundle.js`

Neste projeto o retorno da API é processado por um módulo (ES6 / commonjs), e haverá momentos em que a API irá retornar qual classe/método JavaScript deverá ser executado no Browser. Dessa forma, o nome da classe e do método serão conhecidos a partir de variáveis do tipo string.

Como exemplo, tenho o seguinte cenário:

- main.ts: entrypoint
- MyModule.ts: módulo que faz as chamadas AJAX, recebe o retorno e chama o método devolvido pela API.
- MyGlobal.glob.ts: Classe com exemplo de um dos métodos que poderão ser chamados pelo callback de `MyModule.ts`

Arquivo `main.ts`:

```
import { MyModule } from './MyModule';

MyModule.callApi();
```

Arquivo `MyModule.ts`:

```
import { MyGlobal } from './MyGlobal.glob';

export class MyModule {
    public static callApi() {
        /**
         * Este método faz uma chamada AJAX
         * E passa JSON do retorno para o callback
         */
        let retorno = {
            class: 'MyGlobal',
            method: 'bar',
        };
        this.callback(retorno);
    }

    public static callback(retorno: any) {
        eval(retorno.class + '.' + retorno.method + '();');
    }
}
```

Arquivo `MyGlobal.glob.ts`:

```
export class MyGlobal {
    public static foo() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static bar() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Ao executar o código acima, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyGlobal is not defined
>     at eval (eval at callback (main.js:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
>     at Function.callback (main.js:1)
>     at Function.callApi (main.js:1)
>     at main.js:1
>     at main.js:1
```

Como chamar estes métodos, a partir de strings, sendo que, após compilados pelo webpack estes "nomes originais das classes/métodos" estão inacessíveis?

Comment: Como está seu arquivo de configuração do Webpack?